# XMLHttpRequest and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I take inputs from a form. The inputs contains simple arithmetic operation like 2+3. The input is taken properly as far as i can say. Here chunk has small portion of the input from the input field of the form. As you can see when alert(chuck) gives 2+3 (the right thing) but the response that i get after sending the '2+3' to calculate.php as parameter is 2 3 (2 space 3). My calculate.php simply has something like echo $_GET['param'].

I don't have much experience on this topic. What is the problem here?

```
chunk = theInput.substring(0,3);
alert(chunk); //output is 2+3
document.getElementById("txtHint3").innerHTML = chunk;//output is 2+3
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var response = this.responseText;
    alert(response);  // But here output is 2 3
    document.getElementById("txtHint223").innerHTML = response;  // And same here  is 2 3               
        }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "calculate.php?param="+chunk,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: You should use a framework such as jQuery instead of trying to do this manually. Your code is unlikely to work with all browsers.

Comment: It might also have been useful to see your PHP code as that is doing most of the work here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` represents a space in the query string. Use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to properly encode the value:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "calculate.php?param="+encodeURIComponent(chunk),true);
```

Comment: Thanks... It works now...

Can you give me small explanation why is it necessary?

Comment: Because the query string uses percent encoding. Some characters have special meaning (like `+`). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding